# HTML5 Style Examples In the Wild?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know of any good examples of usage of HTML5 elements that are well-styled out on the intertubes?

Specifically, I'm curious to see `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<meter>`, `<nav>`, `<header>` and so on.

I'm specifically *not* interested in video, audio, offline or drag-n-drop files.  Just the cosmetic stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I'm looking for good html5 examples in the wild I generally check http://html5gallery.com/. Its been a pretty solid resource thus far. You are probably aware that support for these elements is a bit lacking in even many of the newest browsers.

Comment: That's an excellent resource!  And more than that, there are some really gorgeous designs showcased there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [HTML5doctor.com](http://html5doctor.com/) (Run by Bruce Lawson of Opera) is a great resource for HTML5 information, but also a great way to see how HTML5 can be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

(sorry, can’t leave a comment yet)
re: @Greco’s answer, I’d warn anyone away from using w3schools as a reference—the link provided still has elements that were dropped from the spec months ago. You could do much better for HTML5 reference, such as the [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) and [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) links already mentioned.

Comment: +1 because a) you're right and b) you need the reputation. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll love [Full Frontal's](http://2009.full-frontal.org/) website, since it was done exclusively in HTML5.

Comment: Nice.  This is the sort of thing I'm keen to see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would just like to point out that [HTML5Doctor](http://html5doctor.com) isn't just run by Bruce Lawson, there are 6 of us in total! Hopefully you're finding it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The chapter in Mark Pilgrim's [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) on semantics is an excellent primer on using the [elements you mention](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html).

Be careful about calling them 'cosmetic' though, wars have been started over less ;)